# DB partition in Ora 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, partitioning

I need to  select a date from system param for which the partition needs to be created and then need to create the partition using a stored Procedure. ANy guidance.
Oracle 11g is being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use dynamic PL/SQL something like:

```
select the_date into l_date from system_parameters where...;

execute immediate 'alter table mytable add partition p_' || replace(l_date,'-','')
|| ' values less than (to_date(''' || l_date || ''',''DD-MON-YYYY'')';
```

Answer (score 3):

Ronan,

maybe you can adopt interval partitioning? You are using 11g so interval partitioning is available to you. This generates partitions on an is needed base, when the data is inserted and the partition that is needed is not yet available.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer from @ik_zelf, if you are going to implement a partiotion over date, and want to make as and when the date comes, Go for interval Partioning. There would be no need for a Stored Procedure as well.

Its a new feature in the Oracle 11g. Which Creates partiotioning for particular intervals when the records are inserted, so you need not worry on the new partitions. The new Partiotions would be given a system name as well like SYS_PXXX..

This is how go for Interval Partition..

```
CREATE TABLE interval_tab (
  id           NUMBER,
  code         VARCHAR2(10),
  description  VARCHAR2(50),
  created_date DATE
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (created_date)
INTERVAL(NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1,'MONTH')) -- change to 12 for an year  
(
   PARTITION part_01 values LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2012','DD-MON-YYYY'))
);
```

Interval Partition has nothing to do with the earlier Partition, the last partition created before interval would be the transition point here.

You can also go with the

ALTER TABLE way to ADD PARTITION as well..